# Parsing array of JSON arrays in Groovy

Tags: java, json, google-app-engine, facebook, groovy

I  have the following string from a REST JSON response:

```
[
   {
      "uid":10512213,
      "name":"Bob"
   },
   {
      "uid":7208201,
      "name":"John"
   },
   {
      "uid":10570,
      "name":"Jim"
   },
   {
      "uid":1799657,
      "name":"Sally"
   }
]
```

The rest response definition is from Facebook: [FB REST Link](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/api)

I am using Google App Engine + GAELYK which runs in Jetty.

What is the best way to convert the above into **array** of **maps** in Groovy on the Server.  (This would probably have to recurse through the response)

I am looking for something easy that doesn't include a lot of libraries.  (I dont have maven)

Comment: Go to http://json.org/ and pick a class that will meet your needs.

Comment: I tried using JSONObject but that failed on the first character.  It didn't like [ .  I think I need to convert the string into an Array first and then use JSONObject on each individual item from json.org.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

### EDIT:  Groovy since 1.8.0 has an integrated JsonSlurper:

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

// Example Response Data
def restResponse = '[{"uid":10512213, "name":"Bob"},{"uid":7208201, "name":"John"},{"uid":10570, "name":"Jim"},{"uid":1799657, "name":"Sally"}]'

// Parse the response
def list = new JsonSlurper().parseText( restResponse )

// Print them out to make sure
list.each { println it }
```

### Old answer below:

Use JsonSlurper...

An example script to read that response would be:

```
@Grab('net.sf.json-lib:json-lib:2.3:jdk15')
import net.sf.json.groovy.JsonSlurper

// Example Response Data
def restResponse = '[{"uid":10512213, "name":"Bob"},{"uid":7208201, "name":"John"},{"uid":10570, "name":"Jim"},{"uid":1799657, "name":"Sally"}]'

// Parse the response
def list = new JsonSlurper().parseText( restResponse )

// Print them out to make sure
list.each { println it }
```

This outputs:

```
[uid:10512213, name:Bob]
[uid:7208201, name:John]
[uid:10570, name:Jim]
[uid:1799657, name:Sally]
```

As you can see, `list` is a list of Maps, so if you just wanted a list of the names for example, you could just do:

```
def names = list.name
```

To use this in your Gaelyk app, you should just need to [download json-lib-2.3-jdk15.jar from here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/json-lib/files/) and do something similar (without the @Grab then, as you'll have the jar in your `WEB-INF/lib` folder.

--edit--

Looking around, found [this page showing the dependencies](http://json-lib.sourceforge.net/) for json-lib

- [jakarta commons-lang 2.4](http://archive.apache.org/dist/commons/lang/binaries/)
- [jakarta commons-beanutils 1.7.0](http://archive.apache.org/dist/commons/beanutils/binaries/)
- [jakarta commons-collections 3.2](http://archive.apache.org/dist/commons/collections/binaries/)
- [ssh linuxs](http://archive.apache.org/dist/commons/logging/binaries/)
- [ezmorph 1.0.6](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ezmorph/)

The @Grab in the test script does a lot of background work for you

Comment: I believe so...but it won't work on the app engine when you deploy your gaelyk app

Comment: The easiest process was to run the script above which downloaded the jars into the .groovy directory. (I had to download ivy to get @Grab to work)  I then copied the jars to the lib directory.

Comment: and if we have "name : {last : smith , first : stan} " ?

Comment: What are you trying to get?

Answer (score 8):

JSON Arrays starts with a `[` character and ends with a `]` character. JSON object starts with a `{` and ends with `}`.

If you go to JSON.org, you can download JSONArray.java. Use that to create a JSON array. You then loop through the array `for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++)` and retrieve each JSON object by calling `array.getJSONObject(i);` which returns `JSONObject`. From there, get the respective attribute value, e.g. `long uid = json.getLong("uid");`

Hope this helps.