# Read json from jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-groovy

Im trying to read a json file from within a jenkinsfile with grovvy script. Im using the pipeline-utility-steps-plugin, which allows to read the json file as string with the following.

```
def projects = readJSON file: "${env.WORKSPACE}\\Projects.json"
```

after reading the doc, i was thinking i could get out with something like this, but i surely do something wrong because result is null?

```
projects.project[1].name
```

Now my problem is i cant seem to figure out how i get the **name** of number 2 out? Please help me out

Content of the Projects.json

```
    {
  "projects": {
    "project": [
      {
        "name": "PackingStation",
        "solution": "PackingStation\\BLogic.Applications.PackingStation.sln",
        "analysisFiles": "BLogic.Applications.PackingStation.exe"
      },
      {
        "name": "MasterData",
        "solution": "MasterData\\BLogic.Applications.MasterData.sln",
        "analysisFiles": "BLogic.Applications.MasterData.exe"
      },
      {
        "name": "OrderManager",
        "solution": "OrderManager\\BLogic.Applications.OrderManager.sln",
        "analysisFiles": "BLogic.Applications.OrderManager.exe"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are accessing it wrong. `projects` in `projects.project[1].name` refers to the variable defined here `def projects = readJSON file: "${env.WORKSPACE}\\Projects.json"`.

You have again inner json key as `projects`. So please use `projects.projects.project[1].name` to access the value. Hope this helps.

Comment: Could you point me to something that help me if i wanna iterate through the projects.projects.project collection?

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3855232/parsing-array-of-json-arrays-in-groovy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3855232/parsing-array-of-json-arrays-in-groovy)

Comment: indeed an unfortunate naming "projects", there is one too many objects named "projects"